# What is the best way in ES6 to merge 2 vectors of objects based on their objects props value?

Tags: javascript, vector, ecmascript-6

Given these 2 vectors of objects:

```
dbVector = [
  {name: 'one', qty: 1, id: 'id10'},
  {name: 'two', qty: 2, id: 'id20'},
  {name: 'three', qty: 3, id: 'id30'},
  {name: 'for', qty: 4, id: 'id40'},
];

localVector = [
  {name: 'two', qty: 1, id: 'id20'},
  {name: 'for', qty: 1, id: 'id40'},
];
```

What is the best way to merge them so that the qty's get updated based on the object id.

```
result = [
  {name: 'one', qty: 1, id: 'id10'},
  {name: 'two', qty: 3, id: 'id20'},
  {name: 'three', qty: 3, id: 'id30'},
  {name: 'for', qty: 5, id: 'id40'},
];
```

At the moment I am doing it this way:

```
const merge = (a, b, id) => a.filter( aa => !b.find ( bb => aa[id] === bb[id]) ).concat(b);
result = merge(localVector , dbVector , 'id');
```

But the qty's don't get added.

Comment: Try to avoid finding "the best" way of doing anything. Do it some way, then assess against your limitations/requirements. Then improve if necessary. Not to say, that abstract and universal "the best" does not exist.

Comment: If you have any way to make this work, share your code. We want to help you out, not inventing stuff but fixing it.

Comment: sry, I edited the post to reflect my current stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and update with each element of `localVector`.

```js
var dbVector = [{ name: 'one', qty: 1, id: 'id10' }, { name: 'two', qty: 2, id: 'id20' }, { name: 'three', qty: 3, id: 'id30' }, { name: 'for', qty: 4, id: 'id40' }],
    localVector = [{ name: 'two', qty: 1, id: 'id20' }, { name: 'for', qty: 1, id: 'id40' }],
    map = new Map(dbVector.map(o => [o.id, o]));

localVector.forEach(o => map.get(o.id).qty += o.qty);

console.log(dbVector);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome, neat and cool, just one thing in case local has objects that db doesn't then we need to do this:  localVector.forEach( o => map.get(o.id) ? map.get(o.id).qty += o.qty : dbVector.push(o) );  Thank you.

Comment: you could use [`Map#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) for the map to check: `localVector.forEach( o => map.has(o.id) ? map.get(o.id).qty += o.qty : dbVector.push(o) ); `

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```js
let dbVector = [
  {name: 'one', qty: 1, id: 'id10'},
  {name: 'two', qty: 2, id: 'id20'},
  {name: 'three', qty: 3, id: 'id30'},
  {name: 'for', qty: 4, id: 'id40'},
];

let localVector = [
  {name: 'two', qty: 1, id: 'id20'},
  {name: 'for', qty: 1, id: 'id40'},
];

function searchLocalVector(name, id){
  let idx = 0;
  for(let obj of localVector){
    if(obj.name == name && obj.id == id){
      return idx;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  return -1;
}

for(let i=0;i <dbVector.length; i++){
  let idx = searchLocalVector(dbVector[i].name, dbVector[i].id);
  while(idx > -1){
    dbVector[i].qty += localVector[idx].qty;
    localVector.splice(idx, 1);
    idx = searchLocalVector(dbVector[i].name, dbVector[i].id);
  }
}

dbVector.concat(localVector);

console.log(dbVector)
```